# In MIT Scheme/Racket, can a value be both the operator and operand? i.e. (lambda (y) (y y))

Tags: scheme, racket, currying, sicp

For the function foo6, give a Curried application of the procedure which evaluates to 3.

```
(define foo6
  (lambda (x)
    (x (lambda (y) (y y)))))
```

I've defined a foo7 to see how the last line works

```
(define foo7 (lambda (y) (y y)))
```

Is there some "y" that can both be the operator and the operand?

Edit: The question should read:

Is there some "y" that can both be the operator and the operand that will not cause an error or infinite loop?

Question taken from the Structure and Interpretation of Computer Program (SICP) Sample Programming assignments:
https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/psets/index.html

From the "Introductory assignment," Exercise 11:

- PDF Version: https://github.com/yangchenyun/learning-sicp/raw/master/practices/assignments/01.introductory-assignment/ps1_1.pdf
- PS (Original Version):
  https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/psets/ps1/ps1_1.ps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Scheme and Racket are both Lisp1s which means they only have one namespace and thus. the variable `v` can be any value including procedures.

The second you see something like `(lambda (y) (y y))` it obvious what type `y` is a procedure by the way it is being applied. For any other values than a procedure it would end with a application error:

```
((lambda (y) (y y)) 5)
; ERROR: application: 5 is not a procedure
```

The procedure itself will probably expect itself as an argument so we can assume some sort of omega or z combinator.

We have higher order procedures you pass functions as values in operand position and to use them just put then in operator position:

```
(define (times n p)
  (lambda (arg)
    (let loop ((n n) (acc arg))
      (if (<= n 0)
          acc
          (loop (sub1 n) (p acc))))))

(define double (lambda (v) (+ v v)))
(define test (times 3 double))
(test 5) ; ==> 40
```

Scheme is not alone on having this feature. The same code as above can be expressed just as easily in JavaScript as it also only have one namespace and `parseInt(x)` evaluates the variable `parseInt` to a value that gets applied with the argument you get from evaluating the variable `x`. They are just two variables, nothing special.

**EDIT**

Here is an example where `(lambda (y) (y y))` is used in something usefull.

```
;; the Z combinator 
(define Z
  (lambda (f)
    ((lambda (y)
       (y y))
     (lambda (g)
       (f (lambda args (apply (g g) args)))))))

(define (fib n)
  ((Z (lambda (helper)
        (lambda (n a b)
          (if (zero? n)
              a
              (helper (- n 1) b (+ a b))))))
   n 0 1))

(fib 10) ; ==> 55
```

The Z combinator is the Y combinator for eager languages. It makes it possibly for self reference without mutating the environment.

Comment: Can foo7 be applied with some value for y that doesn't cause an error? i.e. '(foo7 <operator/expression>) '  Please note that the question asks for a (curried) application of foo6, not the definition.  Thanks for the reply @Sylwester!

Comment: @watchtheblur Yes. you can do `(foo7 foo7)`. It will produce an infinite loop, but no errors.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it doesn't help with the application of foo6.  I'll edit the question to reflect that.  Thanks again @Sylwester!

Comment: @watchtheblur You did look at my edit where your code is part of a a Z combinator and works perfectly to calculate fibonacci?

Comment: .@Sylwester Just read the edit now, and it's fascinating!  I've never come across the Z combinator.  Still, It isn't clear how the Z combinator can be used to derived a curried application of foo6 to evaluate to 3.  Perhaps my original question (in the title) might not be useful in figuring out how to eventually get foo6 to evaluate to 3?

Comment: @watchtheblur The question opens the post, but it is not your question rather than the assignment from SICP. I thought the scope of the post were the "Is there"-questions. However you can try `(foo6 (lambda (p) 3))`

Comment: That works!  Is this because `(lambda (p) 3)` creates a function that always returns 3?   For instance: `((lambda (p) 3) 54321)` returns 3.  I'm still confused though:  Since MIT scheme follows applicative evaluation, why does `(lambda (p) 3)` not cause `(lambda (y) (y y))` to evaluate?  Won't it evaluate all operands, even if the function itself always return 3?

Comment: @watchtheblur `(lambda (y) (y y))` gets evaluated to a function that is never called.

Comment: It's much clearer now! Thanks for the explainations!

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
(define (foobar n)
  ((foo6
    (lambda (u) (u (lambda (y)
                     (lambda (n)
                       (if (zero? n)
                           1
                           (* n ((y y) (- n 1)))))))))
   n))
```

Y?       I mean, *why*? Because

```
  (foo6 x)
=
  (x (lambda (y) (y y))
=
  (x u)             where u = (lambda (y) (y y))
                    i.e. (u y) = (y y)
```

So the argument to `foo6` should be a function `x` expecting `u` such that `u y = y y`. So we give it the function  such that

```
  (foobar n)
=
   ((foo6 x) n)
=
    ((x u) n)               
=
     ((u y) n)                 so, x = (lambda (u) (u (lambda (y) (lambda (n) ...))))
=
      ((y y) n)              so, y = (lambda (y) (lambda (n) ...))
=
       ((lambda (n)
          (if (zero? n)
            1
            (* n ((y y) (- n 1)))))
        n)
```

and later, when / if `((y y) (- n 1))` needs to be evaluated, the same `(lambda (n) ...)` function is arrived at again as the result of `(y y)` application, and is used again when / if `((y y) (- (- n 1) 1))` needs to be evaluated.

Try it! What's `(foobar 5)` evaluating to? <sub>(ʎʇuǝʍʇpuɐpǝɹpunɥǝuo)</sub>

So, everything fits. Do u see y?

---

`(lambda (y) (y y))` actually has a name: it is "**U** combinator".